# Is there terminology for a sum of maps where every map is not null-homotopic?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Consider maps $f_1,\dots,f_m \colon \Sigma X \longrightarrow Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are CW complexes.

When considering the sum of either the maps themselves

$$\bigvee f_i \colon \Sigma X \longrightarrow Y$$

or the homotopy classes

$$ \sum_{i}[f_i] \in \left[ \Sigma X , Y\right]$$

is there terminology which indicates that every term in the sum is not null-homotopic? For example, the *"irreducible"* sum $ \sum_{i}[f_i] \in \left[ \Sigma X , Y\right]$, or some such thing?

Comment: 1) I'd rather not name this property "irreducibility" because a group of homotopy classes may as well be divisible 2) this property per se seems unreasonable because it's not invariant under self homotopy equivalence of domain (pinching a small piece of suspension).

Comment: @DenisT. Thank you for your comment. I agree entirely with you about the word "irreducibility". Could you elaborate on your remark about invariance under self-homotopy equivalence of the domain?